# searching for matching items powershell "-icontain" & "ilike"

Tags: powershell

i try to filter objects in a directory if they contain in my filter. i got the problem, that the files that i dont want to filter, also contain my files in its names.

The files i want to filter look like : `0000.pdf`, `0001.tsv`,  `0065.png`
the Syntax is the same, every item i want to filter, starts with "00", contains a dot, and after the dot there are tree characters , like "png", "tif" or "doc"

the files i dont want to filter look like:
`batman_N_#_0000.xls`, `spiderman_N_#_0022.xls`,`bane_N_#_0020.png`

my code looks like:

```
if($foldercontentz -ilike "00*.*"){

Add-Content -path $destinationFolderSave\0___missingFiles.txt -value $folderDirection 

}
```

is there a better way to filter it, or can i filter those files, with another method, is it even possible? or have i to change the files.
i tought it would filter the files because my objects starts with "00" everytime, and the files i dont want to filter not.

Edit:

```
$pdfFiles = "Desktop\Import\superheros\"

$sidepaths = Get-ChildItem -path $pdfFiles -Directory

$filesfolder = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]

for ($i = 0; $i -le $sidepaths.count; $i++) {
    $filesfolder.add($sidepaths[$i])
}

for ($i = 0; $i -le $filesfolder.count; $i++) {
    $folder = $pdfFiles + $filesfolder[$i]
    #write-host $folder

    $folder | foreach {
        $contentfolder = Get-ChildItem $_
        $location = $directories[$i]

        if ($contentfolder -contains "00*.*" ) {
            #Write-Output $contentfolder "haaadadasd" $filesfolder[$i]
            Add-Content -path $pdfFiles\0___missingFiles.txt -value $contentfolder
        }
        
        # ...
    }

    # ...
}
```

Comment: What is `$foldercontentz`?

Comment: This should get you the files you're looking for `Get-ChildItem -Path $pdfFiles -Filter 00* -Include *.png, *.tif, *.doc -Recurse -File`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
$rootFolder = 'X:\Desktop\Import\superheros'             # path to the superheros folder
$outFile    = 'X:\Desktop\Import\0___missingFiles.txt'   # full path and filename for the output file
# look for Files with a name beginning with '00' and write their full path and name to the output file.
(Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder -File -Filter '00*.*' -Recurse).FullName | Add-Content -Path $outFile
```